# 3SAT and directed graph

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, satisfiability

Given a 3SAT instance (a Boolean expression in three conjunctural normal form), we draw a directed graph, where for each Boolean variable $x_{i}$ we have the nodes $x_{i}$ and $!x_{i}$; for each clause, for example $\left(x_{a} \vee x_{b} \vee x_{c}\right)$, we draw the following arrows $!x_{a}x_{b}$, $!x_{a}x_{c}$, $!x_{b}x_{a}$, $!x_{b}x_{c}$, $!x_{c}x_{a}$, $!x_{c}x_{b}$.

Is it possible understand from the graph if there is a variable $x_{i}$ such that $x_{i}\Leftrightarrow !x_{i}$ ($!x_{i}$ is $not\left(x_{i}\right)$)?

Comment: Your instance implies $x_i \Leftrightarrow \overline{x_i}$ iff it is unsatisfiable. Given that SAT is NP-complete, there is probably no easy way to tell.

Comment: You might be interested in the [Resolution proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to build the 2-SAT implication graph for 3-SAT.

In 2-SAT, $(x_a \vee x_b)$ may indeed be considered as 2 implications, $\neg x_a \Rightarrow x_b$ and $\neg x_b \Rightarrow x_a$.

The problem is that $(x_a \vee x_b \vee x_c)$ is not equivalent to any of the 6 implications like $\neg x_b \Rightarrow x_a$, as $x_c$ is sufficient to satisfy the clause.
You may eventually have $(\neg x_a \wedge \neg x_b) \Rightarrow x_c$ or $\neg x_a \Rightarrow (x_b \vee x_c)$, but neither let you build such implication graph.

Comment: Optidad, you are right, but, in my opinion, we can write the implication $\neg x_{a} \Rightarrow \left(x_{b}\vee x_{c}\right)$ in the directed graph as follow. We add to the graph a double node _db_, that is a node with one ingoing arrow and two outgoing arrows. Then we draw the arrow from $\neg x_{a}$ to _db_, the arrow from _db_ to $x_{b}$ and the arrow from _db_ to $x_{c}$. After we have added to the graph all the implications of the given 3SAT, we can find the implication $x_{a} \Rightarrow \neg x_{a}$, if it exists, as follow: (see next comment)...

Comment: We make a _back_ breadth first search in the graph from $\neg x_{a}$, where _back_ means that the search goes from the node $a$ to the node $b$ if and only if there is an arrow from $b$ to $a$. If the search meets a double node _dn_, the search must visit _dn_ from both outgoing arrows of _dn_ before visit the node that is on the ingoing arrow of _dn_. In such a way, if the search from $\neg x_{a}$ reaches $ x_{a}$, this means that $x_{a} \Rightarrow \neg x_{a}$. In the same way we can find if $\neg x_{a} \Rightarrow  x_{a}$ and therefore if $x_{a} \Leftrightarrow \neg x_{a}$.

Comment: @Mario_Giambarioli Just try it on a simple case of 3-SAT, you will realise quickly that it does not work. First, there is no mean to go reversly in an implication graph as $a \Rightarrow b$ is independant of $b \Rightarrow a$. Also, you are not able to treat the statement "OR" to use such double nodes.